# Passing values with POST not working - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code.. Am trying to figure out why the wEx1 value is not being passed to the PHP code but the wDate is.  I have the  with the name='wEx1' attribute and I have tried both straight forward $_POST[] to get it and also the escape string even though it is not an input field from the user.  Either way I am unable to get it to show up on an echo statement on the php side.  Any thoughts and help are appreciated!

```
<form class='navbar-form' method='post' action='enterWorkoutPlan.php' onsubmit='return validateWorkoutPlan()' name='workoutPlanForm'>
    <div class='form-group'>

    ...other stuff here..

        <b>Exercise 1: </b>

        <select class='form-control' name='wEx1'>
            <!-- Have default be Select Exercise for how many exercises are chosen check -->
            <option value='Select exercise' selected>Select exercise</option>
            <?php
                $sql2 = "SELECT exName FROM exercises";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql2);
                if ($result2){
                    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
                        echo "
                          <option value='".$row2['exID']."'>".$row2['exName']."</option>";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<script>confirm('Error pulling exercises list');</script>";
                }
            ?>                                                  
        </select><br>
    ...other stuff here..

    </div>

    <br><br>
    <input type='submit' value='Save Workout' class='btn btn-primary'>
</form>
```

My PHP page that accepts the values looks like this..

```
<?php
include("config.php");
include("userInfo.php");
session_start();

ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

$wUserID = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["wUserID"]);
$wDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["wDate"]);
$wEx1 = $_POST["wEx1"];
$wEx2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["wEx2"]);
$wEx3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["wEx3"]);
$wEx4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["wEx4"]);
$wEx5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["wEx5"]);
$wEx6 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["wEx6"]);
$wEx7 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["wEx7"]);
$wEx8 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["wEx8"]);
$wEx9 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["wEx9"]);
$wEx10 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["wEx10"]);
.... etc..
```

Comment: In your receiving PHP file (which I assume is the enterWorkoutPlan.php file?), can you add var_dump($_POST); to see what is in the POST array? I do not see wDate in the posted HTML, so I assume it is there somewhere. Also, I minor thing: in the HTML attribute values should have double quotes instead of single quotes. In addition, where you query the exercises list, you only get the name, and not the ID, so the 'value' to each entry is likely an empty string, which the var_dump() should show. Another way to check the select options is by viewing the browser page source after the page load.

Comment: Thanks @PaulT. I did the dump and got array(12) { ["wUserID"]=> string(1) "2" ["wDate"]=> string(10) "2017/09/01" ["wEx1"]=> string(0) "" ["wEx2"]=> string(15) "Select exercise"  .. so I am not seeing anything for that wEx1 still.  Still looking into it.. Tried the double quotes as well.

Comment: Yes, empty strings. I know that my previous comment is long, but see what I said about the query that populates the options for the select. `["wEx1"]=> string(0)` means an empty (0-length) string, so a selection was made. Note that that `wExt2` DOES have the default 'selected' option of `Select Exercise`.

Comment: Oh thanks, I read that but didnt realize that was the issue, I will try that out now.

Comment: Fixed :) Thanks that worked

Answer (score -1):

In addition, where you query the exercises list, you only get the name, and not the ID, so the 'value' to each entry is likely an empty string, which the var_dump() should show. Another way to check the select options is by viewing the browser page source after the page load. – Paul T. 23 mins ago

Comment: Did you really copy part of a comment lmao

Comment: Retro just wants karma.